# Fixed the indentation of VS2015 for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, formatting, indentation

Editing python in VS2015, my current code is from internet so it has indentation of 4 spaces. When I'm editing it, any new line will have indentation of a tab.

The short cut ctrl+k , ctrl+F doesn't work.

Is there any quick way to fix this (My guess would be a find/replace all)?

Comment: There's often a indentation replacing option under "edit". At least that where it's in in IntelliJ. Something like "convert tabs to spaces".

Comment: notepad++ also has this option to convert tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. 
In VS2015 menu, Edit, advanced, there is "Tabify Selected Lines" to convert spaces to tab. The "Untabify Selected Lines" will replace Tab with spaces.

No keyboard short cuts. :(